# Properties of exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Define a function E on $R$ as the inverse to the function $L(y)= \int_{1}^{y}\frac{1}{t}\operatorname{d}t,\quad y\in(0,\infty)$

such that $ E(L(y))=y, y\in (0,\infty)$

and $L(E(x))=x, , x \in R$.

I have to prove that

(i) E is strictly increasing, continuous, differentiable on R and $ E'(x)=E(x)$

(ii) $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} E(x) = +\infty $ and $\lim\limits_{ x\rightarrow-\infty} E(x)=0$.

Please suggest how to prove the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to show easily that $L(y)$ is increasing, differentiable, and satisfies $\lim_{y\to\infty} L(y) = \infty$ and $\lim_{y\to0+} L(y) = -\infty$. These properties alone should suffice to prove everything in (i) and (ii) other than the exact formula for $E'(x)$.

As for $E'(x)=E(x)$, what happens if you take the derivative of both sides of the equation $L(E(x)) = x$?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer :)  $ L'(E(x))=1$ implies that $\frac{1}{E(x)}.E'(x)=1.$ Can you please let me know how to prove $ E(x)$ approaches infinity as x does.

Comment: You have an increasing function $L(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} L(x) = \infty$, and you have its inverse $E(x)$. You want to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} E(x) = \infty$. What is the definition of this statement you're trying to prove? You should be able to use your knowledge of $L(x)$ to show that $E(x)$ satisfies the appropriate definition.